# How to disconnect and reconnect pppoe in D-link 2750u

Tags: networking, router

I have a D-link 2750u Modem and I want to disconnect/reconnect my PPPOE in order to obtain a new IP adress on demand using Telnet

My solution for now is just to remove the ADSL cable, and plug it in again but it's not practical

I tried a few commands like

```
ifconfig ppp0.1 down
ifconfig ppp0.1 up
```

But they are not working, the internet go down and won't come back until I reboot my modem

Comment: I think the OP wants to be able to switch his IP address on demand.

Comment: @nevin Williams, hmm I guess I mis-read part of it. "But they are not working, the internet go down and won't come back until I reboot my modem" is what made me think he is looking for a workaround for a larger underlying issue.

Comment: He probably has to HUP or re-initialize `pppd` after the interface goes away, if it's a linux/unix-like OS.

To add to your troubleshooting steps:  Some finicky DSL/Cable/other network issues of no specific cause can often be put to rest by plugging the device directly into a wall socket, rather than a power strip or 6x wall expander.  Network devices can have ground-loop hums much the same way and reason audio devices get them...  except often more easily because of the phone/cable/ethernet connections, all which need good, direct ground/neutral power to correct.

Comment: Actually I found the solution, it was a simple "adsl connection --up" command that was enough for the PPPOE to reconnect

Comment: @martin bayen, If you found the solution. You should post it as an answer with as much detail as possible. That way other people with the same model modem will find in their searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bit with my modem ,  I found that when I was preforming this command

```
ifconfig ppp0.1 down
```

the interface ppp0.1 get deleted or something ( not sure) but it is impossible to get it up and running again

So I tried with the command

```
adsl connection --up
```

and it work perfectly to reconnect the adsl connection, and with the minumum downtime

Note: 
You don't have to preform

> adsl connection --down

only the --up is enough for reconnecting